# Getting "per_page must be between 1 (inclusive) and 100 (inclusive)" while requesting the categories in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, pagination, woocommerce-rest-api

https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/categories/?per_page=150&consumer_key=ck_991580c4b11ae619bef763195f67c311aa2bc&consumer_secret=cs_07cacbb022086cf185beb0145fe0e5db01c57&currentLanguage=en

```
   {
        "code": "rest_invalid_param",
        "message": "Invalid parameter(s): per_page",
        "data": {
            "status": 400,
            "params": {
                "per_page": "per_page must be between 1 (inclusive) and 100 (inclusive)"
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get the 150 categories from the woo-commerce using the wp JSON API. I can't make it 100.is there any way to fix this using the hooks.

Comment: The answer is no. You can get more information here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/
But you can pass page number in you case to get data properly

Comment: @BrijeshDhanani is there any way we can do hardcode 150. because I am requesting from my mobile app. so I can't change there

Comment: check my answer

Comment: or is there any way to write the query while we are calling

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'rest_product_query', 'product_override_per_page' );

/* 
 * params is the query array passed to WP_Query
*/
function product_override_per_page( $params ) {
    if ( isset( $params ) AND isset( $params[ 'posts_per_page' ] ) ) {
        $params[ 'posts_per_page' ] = "200";
    }

return $params;
}
```

Don't miss to replace customer with your post type in hook

Comment: Is it Worked ??

Comment: `{
    "code": "rest_invalid_param",
    "message": "Invalid parameter(s): per_page",
    "data": {
        "status": 400,
        "params": {
            "per_page": "per_page must be between 1 (inclusive) and 100 (inclusive)"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: what you have tried in functions.php file. can you please share??

Comment: add_action( 'rest_product_cat_query', 'customer_override_per_page' );

/* 
 * params is the query array passed to WP_Query
*/
function customer_override_per_page( $params ) {
  if ( isset( $params ) AND isset( $params[ 'posts_per_page' ] ) ) {
    $params[ 'posts_per_page' ] = "200";
  }
  return $params;
}

Comment: https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/categories/?per_page=150&consumer_key=ck_991580c4b11ae619bef763195f65d67c311aa2bc&consumer_secret=cs_07cacbb022086cf185beb0145fe0810e5db01c57&currentLanguage=en

Comment: Just use product instead of product cat. Check my edited answer

Comment: still not working you did edit your answer. even the request is not going in the hook you provided.

Comment: Last option is https://wpscholar.com/blog/increasing-the-max-results-returned-from-the-wordpress-rest-api/ Please check and let me know if it is working

Comment: the request is going inside of the hook. but the result remains the same  `"per_page must be between 1 (inclusive) and 100 (inclusive)"`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/

It looks like the per_page parameter can have any integer value between 1 and 100. So the answer to your question is **NO**

[image]

If you want to hard code

```
/**
 * Retrieves the query params for the collections.
 *
 * @since 4.7.0
 *
 * @return array Query parameters for the collection.
 */
public function get_collection_params() {
    return array(
        'context'  => $this->get_context_param(),
        'page'     => array(
            'description'       => __( 'Current page of the collection.' ),
            'type'              => 'integer',
            'default'           => 1,
            'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
            'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
            'minimum'           => 1,
        ),
        'per_page' => array(
            'description'       => __( 'Maximum number of items to be returned in result set.' ),
            'type'              => 'integer',
            'default'           => 10,
            'minimum'           => 1,
            'maximum'           => 1000,
            'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
            'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
        ),
        'search'   => array(
            'description'       => __( 'Limit results to those matching a string.' ),
            'type'              => 'string',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
            'validate_callback' => 'rest_validate_request_arg',
        ),
    );
}
```

/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-controller.php #L381

Comment: I read the point. but is there any way to do this thing I can code in the core file. the endpoints I have used in mobile apps I can't update there. I am ready to do hard code in core files for know.